# How to programatically press a button inside a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am making an IOS app that has to press an html button within a website in a webview but I am not sure how to format this code. How can I make a button in my app press an html button inside of a website (in webview)? Thanks!

Comment: Your title is a bit unprecise, what about "How to programatically press a button inside a UIWebView" or similar. Xcode is an IDE to help you build iOS, Mac OS, C or C++ apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simulate a click inside the UIWebView programatically.

Comment: I am trying to make a button in my app click on an html button inside of the web view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What function are you calling? You can use "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" to handle javascript.

For example, you have this on the web site.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Then in Xcode you can do this to call the javascript function. This should help you to accomplish what you need.

```
-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender
{
 //This will call the javascript method "myFunction"
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"];  
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do... I am trying to make a button in my app click on an html button inside of the web view. How can I do this?

Comment: I am sorry, but I realized it is a javascipt button in the website, not html... and I believe this is the code for the button in the web view: <input title="Add To Cart Button" tabindex="869" name="pdp_addtocart" value="Add To Cart" type="submit" class="active_step">